# Recommended HDTVs for use with a Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, hdtv

I'm looking to change my current home computer setup and was thinking about hooking up my Early 2009 Mac Mini to a HDTV to use as a general media hub, and for the occasional light desktop work from the sofa :)

Can anyone recommend a HDTV that would work well with the Mini, or provide advice on useful features I should be paying attention to when choosing a HDTV for such a use? (e.g. size/resolution, colour management, VGA/HDMI connection, LCD/Plasma, response time etc.)

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about shopping recommendations are considered off topic on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, this is really rather simple. For the connection, I recommend an HDMI to DVI cable for ease of setup, as any HDTV you get these days should have a HDMI port. As far as the actual display goes, I recommend getting something with a good contrast ratio, and a low refresh rate. Depending on your use, and the size of the screen, the resolution may also be very important.

Let me say from experience that using a webbrowser from the couch with a keyboard in your lap is much more difficult then you would expect.